# How to plot matplotlib on the background?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to plot this image but i dont want it to get focus out of the command line from my IDE.
Is that possible?

```
for z in xrange(submission_data.shape[0]):
    #print "Loaded Image ", z
    img = submission_data[z]
    img = img.reshape(14, 14)

    plt.imshow(img , cmap="gray")

    plt.show(block=False)

    input = raw_input("Enter The digit: ")

    plt.clf()
    plt.close('all')

    if(input == "save"):
        print "Saving ",z
        dir_submission_label = "label_"+str(z)+".gz"
        np.savetxt(fname=dir_submission_label,X=labels)
    else:
        labels[z] = input
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new script with your Graph code in it.
On top of your main script put

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["python","nameOfScriptContainingGraphcode"])
```

What this will do is create a subprocess that will be executed on your command line while you use your IDE. It's like sending other processes on the background.

Comment: you could edit your answer to add details/change formatting, rather than create a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new script with your Graph code in it. On top of your main script put

```
                import subprocess
                ...
                subprocess.call(["python","nameOfScriptContainingGraphcode"])
```

It will execute the script containing the code for your graph in the background